# Form Validation with sum of fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm trying to get this validation code to work. I only want the user to be able to add to the cart when the sum of the fields is equal to 7, if it does not equal 7 then an error should be shown.

Any help would be great as I can't see where I need to change it.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brhx65nL)

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
          var $fieldsSet = $('div.validateFields');
          var MaxSelectionNum = "7"
          var sum = 0;
          // Loop through all inputs with names that start
          // with "option-quantity" and sum their values
          $fieldsSet.find('input[name^="option-quantity"]').each(function() {
              sum += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
          });

          // Set the sum
          $fieldsSet.find('.sum').val(sum);

          var allSumEqualCustomDesc = true;

          if (allSumEqualCustomDesc) {
              $("div.errorQuantity").html("Please select 7 meals").show();
          } else {

              $("div.errorQuantity").hide();

          };

  $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
      type: 'post',
      data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'number\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea'),
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {
          $('#button-cart').button('loading');
      },
      complete: function() {
          $('#button-cart').button('reset');
      },
      success: function(json) {
          $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
          $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

          if (json['error']) {
              if (json['error']['option']) {
                  for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                      var element = $('#input-option' + i.replace('_', '-'));

                      if (element.parent().hasClass('input-group')) {
                          element.parent().after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
                      } else {
                          element.after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
                      }
                  }
              }

              if (json['error']['recurring']) {
                  $('select[name=\'recurring_id\']').after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['recurring'] + '</div>');
              }

              // Highlight any found errors
              $('.text-danger').parent().addClass('has-error');
          }

          if (json['success']) {
              $('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

              $('#cart > button').html('<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total']);

              $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: 0
              }, 'slow');

              $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
          }
      }
    });
 }
 );
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net) or provide us with your html aswell so we can test it ourselves?

Comment: oh sorry, here is the html but it's a dynamic page that I'm using it on
https://jsfiddle.net/brhx65nL/

Comment: No problem, I was able to work out what I needed from your HTML. In my answer below, is two examples on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here are two ways of doing it:**

(Not added the `AJAX` code but i've commented where it should go)

**Example 1:**

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function()
{
    var MaxSelectionNum = "7";
    var sum = 0;

    // Loop through all inputs with names that start
    // with "option-quantity" and sum their values
    $('input[name^="option-quantity"]').each(function()
    {
        console.log(parseInt($(this).val()));
        sum += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
    });

    if (sum < MaxSelectionNum)
    {
        $(".errorQuantity").html("Please select 7 meals").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".errorQuantity").hide();

        // AJAX SHOULD GO HERE!
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/La18Lcns/3/)

**Example 2: (Closer to your original code)**

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function()
{
    var MaxSelectionNum = "7";
    // Set the sum
    var sum = 0;

    // Loop through all inputs with names that start
    // with "option-quantity" and sum their values
    $('input[name^="option-quantity"]').each(function()
    {
        console.log(parseInt($(this).val()));
        sum += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
    });

    $(".sum").html(sum);  

    if ($(document).find('.sum').val(sum) > MaxSelectionNum)
    {
        $(".errorQuantity").hide();

        // AJAX SHOULD GO HERE!
    }
    else
    {
        $(".errorQuantity").html("Please select 7 meals").show();
    }

});
```

[**UPDATED JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/La18Lcns/6/)

**UPDATED (TALKED ABOUT IN COMMENT SECTION):**

[**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/o5wzum1L/7/)

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the reply. I've added the code but it is showing the error and not preventing me from adding to the cart whatever number of meals are selected, even if it equals 7. I thought it was maybe because there are more than one group of fields please see this fiddle to see what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/ztL48qag/

Comment: @user5359040 - Hey, In your JSFIDDLE you're missing the JQuery files on the left hand side from drop down. **Try this** - http://jsfiddle.net/ztL48qag/2/

Comment: thanks, this def works but the total sum of the fields is per div not the total of all the fields in the form. so hthe first div needs to equal 7 and then the next div needs to equal 7

Comment: @user5359040 Check my new JSfiddle example in my answer. It's under the "Added Error Border to input field"

Comment: sorry I don't think i explained myself very well in the last comment, I've edited my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ztL48qag/10/ I tried to change the code to look for the input boxes within the div.option and see if these fields add up to 7 but I don't think I'm editing it in the right place

Comment: @user5359040 I've updated my answer, sorry about that. I've added a way of doing what you want.

Comment: sorry to ask again because I really do appreciate all the help that you have given me so far but is there a way to do it so that it checks the sum within the div.mealoptions and vaildates it off that rather than having to 2 variables at the start because the page is dynamic, so there could be up to 4 div.mealoptions at a time on the page. I have tried to edit your code but I can't see where I'm going wrong http://jsfiddle.net/ztL48qag/31/

Comment: @user5359040 I've changed my answer with updated jsfiddle - If the page is dynamic, just add number to the `mealoptions` class name when it gets generated. So it would be `mealoptions1`, `mealoptions2` etc. Then you just have it loop through each of the classnames. You will see in my example.

Comment: that works great, thank you so so much! only one last question...well fingers crossed :)  I am unable to edit the code that generates the classnames so is there another way that I can target the divs without adding 1, 2, 3 etc?

Comment: @ user5359040 Can you add attribute values like `name=""` or `title=""` or adding a `id`?

Comment: no unfortunately the only way to identify the div is by the class name which is .mealdivs, it's a really inflexible system I know :(

Comment: @user5359040 I can take alook further tonight, but as far as I know the ways i've done it is the right way of doing it. Can I ask why can't you change the classname or identify it different way?

Comment: sorry I've been staring at the specific section for code for so long my brain seems to be stuck in an infinite loop obsessed with just using class names. I checked the full source code again and there is an outer div with an ID http://jsfiddle.net/o5wzum1L/1/

Comment: @user5359040 - I've updated my answer with a clean up of what your latest fiddle was. So if that is what you needed, please could you tick the answer. To say that you've found what you needed?

Comment: thanks for all your help and patience, very much appreciated